# What does it mean when a variable is defined with a subscript but used without one in equations?

Tags: notation

[This article](http://www.onmyphd.com/?p=k-means.clustering)
defines $x_i ,i=1,\dots,n$ where $x$ has a subscript. However succeeding the definition, the formula contains only $x$.

How am I supposed to interpret this generic notation in terms of math?

Comment: Most probably, $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is a *vector* with the given components.

Comment: @MartinR: no, have a look at the paper. $\mathbf x$ is a dummy vector variable taking all values in a cluster. The $\mathbf x_i$ are also vectors.

Comment: That may be. The question should contain all relevant information in itself, and not refer to an external link only (which may become unreachable or go offline in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of *dummy variables*.

In
$$\mathbf x_i,i=1,\cdots n$$

$i$ is a dummy index, meaning that you refer to a set of $n$ points, which are numbered. But you could has well have written

$$\mathbf x_k,k=1,\cdots n$$ with exactly the same meaning. You can use the same trick in summation formulas, like

$$\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf x_j.$$

Finally, the $\mathbf x$ that troubles you is also a dummy variable, used in

$$\sum_{\mathbf x\in \mathbf c}\|\mathbf x-\mu\|_2^2$$ as the range of a summation. They could as well have written

$$\sum_{\mathbf \xi\in \mathbf c}\|\mathbf\xi-\mu\|_2^2.$$

Comment: @ArtTatum: not at all. This defines $\mathbf x$ to be a set of points, not a dummy variable.

Comment: @ArtTatum: this is up to you.

Comment: Hi! Can't we just continue to use $\mathbf x_i$ instead of $\mathbf x$? I.e. $\sum_{\mathbf x_i\in \mathbf c_i}\|\mathbf x_i-\mu_i\|_2^2$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe: sorry, my notation with $\mu_i/c_i$ was misleading. Fixing...

Comment: Hi! But does it matter if we use $\mathbf x_i$ or $\mathbf x$? I.e. aren't $\sum_{\mathbf x\in \mathbf c}\|\mathbf x-\mu\|_2^2$ equivalent to $\sum_{\mathbf x_i\in \mathbf c}\|\mathbf x_i-\mu\|_2^2$?

Comment: @JDoeDoe: matter of taste.